# Panic when attempting to use GORM Joins Preloading

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm attempting to create a simple REST API using go as a learning project. I've run into a snag while trying to populate a `has many` relationship using the `Joins` preload feature of GORM.

As far as I can tell, I have set up the relationships properly, the table structure looks good in the db and the records get inserted, but the following code produces an error:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on slice Value
```

I've produced a minimal example here showing my issue

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Page struct {
    gorm.Model
    Text   string
    BookID uint
}

type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    Pages []Page
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("postgres://postgres:password@host.docker.internal:5432/postgres"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Book{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Page{})
    db.Create(&Book{
        Pages: []Page{
            {Text: "Page One"},
        },
    })
    result := []Book{}
    // errors here
    db.Joins("Pages").Find(&result)

    // works fine
    //  db.Preload("Pages").Find(&result)
}
```

Any guidance on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated, brand new to go.

Comment: you mention the tables have a “has many” relationship. The GORM docs mention, “Join Preload works with one-to-one relationship”. sounds like it might not be compatible with your current design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to docs ([Joins Preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Joins-Preloading)):

> **NOTE** `Join Preload` works with one-to-one relation, e.g: `has one`, `belongs to`

Comment: Appreciate it! I probably read that line a dozen times without properly parsing it. Cheers!